# Отображение списка названий групп из таблицы в ComboBox`е

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Есть две таблицы: Студенты и Группы. Студенты связаны внешним ключом с Группами атрибутом "№ группы". Необходимо сделать подчиненную форму.
Студенты:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Группы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на список выводились названия групп, в комбобоксе было название группы, а сохранялось значение кода группы. Вот форма в дизайнере:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал выставить такие параметры: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И отображает оно правильно при первом проходе, но когда я начинаю возвращаться назад, то значения меняются и сохраняются не только в студентах, но и в группах (приходится каждый раз править названия в таблице с группами)

До:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение - убрал значение в параметре "Text".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]